# Node.js 4 and Node 5 on the same machine running OS X "EL Capitan"

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, osx-elcapitan

I am about to get started with the ionic framework and they stated on their website that they require Node.js 4 and Node 5 does not work at the moment!.

Bummer!! That sounds like a downgrade.

I was wondering what would the best, if there is one, setup to have both, Node 4 and Node 5, installed on my Mac OS X El Capitan and how would I use they.

I would consider VM environments too, but I would like to explore the possibilities on my machine first.

Please advise!

Comment: [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for a version manager. There are two in particular for node.js

[nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and [n](https://github.com/tj/n).

They both allow you to install different versions of node.js and subsequently switch them at will.

You can install a specific version of node with the following commands:

```
nvm install 5.0
n 5.0
```

They both share the similar `use` command to switch installed versions:

```
nvm use 5.0
n use 5.0
```

A nice feature of `n` is that it displays installed versions if you just type `n` and allows you to interactively switch them.

[image]